# Zend Models not being found

Tags: zend-framework, models, autoload

I'm having a strange problem with Zend.  I have an application that works great on localhost, and can access it from outside using my IP address as well.  When I move it to our staging server, it fails to load any of the classes.  I am using autoloading with a modular structure.  All the models are in the Default module, then the models folder.  Static pages work fine, but anything that tries to access a model fails with "Fatal error: Class 'Default_Model_ModelName' not found in (Controller Path & Name)".  I have checked the server and all files are there and are exactly as they were on localhost.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue or what may be happening?  I've looked into everything I can think of and can't see any problems anywhere.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Staging = Linux? CaseSensetive?

Comment: We'll need to see some code samples, names of folders. What's your include path look like when it prints out that error?

Answer (score 1):

Some items to check:

- Did the .htaccess file get moved?  This is really easy to overlook.
- Is the Zend Framework version different?